# Convert string "list" to an object

Tags: python, django

How would you convert this to an object that you can iterate through

```
[{u'pk': u'1', u'quantity': u'2', u'name': u'3mm aliminum sheet', u'size': u'300x322'},{u'pk': u'2', u'quantity': u'1', u'name': u'2mm aliminum sheet', u'size': u'300x322'}]
```

This data is saved as above in a CharField() in my Django model. Now I need to iterate it in the template.

Comment: You should clarify your question, your list is already an object you can iterate through.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Use a JSONField - for an example implementation see [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1478/) - and store the content as valid JSON, rather than a stringified dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "[{u'pk': u'1', u'quantity': u'2', u'name': u'3mm aliminum sheet', u'size': u'300x322'},{u'pk': u'2', u'quantity': u'1', u'name': u'2mm aliminum sheet', u'size': u'300x322'}]"
d = eval(s)
print type(d)
```

This is not a good way of persisting objects. Try to save them using model class.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I am updating my answer. But You should write your question clearly. In your question you even not try to show it as a `strings`. On first look it looks like a `list`.

You can use http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html python `ast` module.

```
In [12]: import ast

In [13]: s = "[{u'pk': u'1', u'quantity': u'2', u'name': u'3mm aliminum sheet', u'size': u'300x322'},{u'pk': u'2', u'quantity': u'1', u'name': u'2mm aliminum sheet', u'size': u'300x322'}]"

In [14]: result = ast.literal_eval(s)

In [15]: result
Out[15]: 
[{u'name': u'3mm aliminum sheet',
  u'pk': u'1',
  u'quantity': u'2',
  u'size': u'300x322'},
 {u'name': u'2mm aliminum sheet',
  u'pk': u'2',
  u'quantity': u'1',
  u'size': u'300x322'}]

In [16]: result[0].get('name')
Out[16]: u'3mm aliminum sheet'
```

Now you can send this new result value to the template.

```
{% for r in result.0 %}
       {{ r.name }}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: @Harry where did you mention this in you question?